# Vba SaveAs at same time if cell changes

Tags: excel, vba

I am very new to VBA and I really appreciate any help!
I have a code to saveas every day at 00:10hrs that works great, and I have a code for the cell change, but I don't know how to combine them...
   It needs to saveas if cell changes, but wait to 00:10hrs, subtract 1 day from the saving date and saveas, since temperature data values belong to previous day. Thank you in advance!

```
'Cell change is at Sheet2
Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.Address = "$C$20" Then
        Call teste 
    End If
If Target.Address = "$G$20" Then
        Call teste
    End If
End Sub

'ThisWorkbook
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
   Application.OnTime TimeValue("00:10:00"), "Abre"
End Sub

'Module1
Sub Abre()
    Application.OnTime TimeValue("00:10:00"), "Abre"
    Dim datestr As String
    datestr = Format(Now, "yyyymmdd, hhmm")
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs "D:\Temperature Data\DailyTemp " & datestr & ".xlsm"
End Sub

'Module2
Sub teste()
MsgBox "Did not work"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31439866/multiple-variable-arguments-to-application-ontime) post, you can pass arguments to `OnTime` function. Change your `Abre` to accept a date, which can be used to save a file and call it with appropriate date from `Worksheet_Change` and `Abre` itself. The code below is not tested, but I think you will get the idea. One thing to check is what happens if your `Worksheet_Change` method get called twice: do you have to cancel previous `OnTime` before calling a new one?

```
'Cell change is at Sheet2
Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.Address = "$C$20" Then
    Call teste
End If
If Target.Address = "$G$20" Then
    Call teste
End If
Dim datestr As String
datestr = Format(Now, "yyyymmdd, hhmm")
Application.OnTime TimeValue("00:10:00"), procedureCalled, , False
procedureCalled = "'Abre """ & datestr & """'"
Application.OnTime TimeValue("00:10:00"), procedureCalled
End Sub

'ThisWorkbook
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Dim datestr As String
    datestr = Format(Now, "yyyymmdd, hhmm")
    procedureCalled = "'Abre """ & datestr & """'"
    Application.OnTime TimeValue("00:10:00"), procedureCalled
End Sub

'Module1
Public procedureCalled As String  '<--variable to keep last scheduled procedure, so you can unshedule it in Worksheet_Change
Sub Abre(savedate As String)
    Dim datestr As String
    datestr = Format(Now, "yyyymmdd, hhmm")
    procedureCalled = "'Abre """ & datestr & """'"
    Application.OnTime TimeValue("00:10:00"), procedureCalled
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs "D:\Temperature Data\DailyTemp " & savedate & ".xlsm"
End Sub

'Module2
Sub teste()
MsgBox "Did not work"
End Sub
```

Comment: It worked while changing the cell values manually, but automatically it waited for the TimeValue (what I wanted) but ignored the cell changes time, saving with the time I saved the macro changes. Do I have to leave Sheet2 active? I need Sheet1 open 24/7! I've tried to understand what the code does but I cannot yet... I am very new to VBA... I really appreciate your help!

Comment: @Automat I updated my code. I added public variable to keep last scheduled procedure. That way it is possible to cancel it in `Worksheet_Change` and prevent from calling it many times. I don't know if this solves problem you described, but you can give it a try ;)