# How do you call a procedure that has parameters on the Application.onTime function?

Tags: vba, excel

How do I call a procedure on the Application.onTime function when the procedure being called has a parameter?

```
Sub popUpReminder(msg As String)
    MsgBox (msg)
End Sub

Sub schedulePopUp()
    Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:05"), "popUpReminder " & """" & "Hello" & """"
End Sub
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiple Variable Arguments to Application.OnTime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31439866/multiple-variable-arguments-to-application-ontime)

Answer (score 2):

### Passing a Method With Parameters as a String

- Enclose the whole procedure with parameters inside single quotes/Chr(39)
- Add space after parameter
- Wrap String values inside double quotes/Chr(35)
- Wrap Dates with hashes/Chr(35)

↑These Rules↑ work for both `Application.OnTime`, `Application.Run` or `Control.OnAction`.

You could do all the above every time or you could just write a subroutine to do it for you.  Or you could just copy and paste the one I wrote:

```
Sub Test()
    Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:01"), WrapMacro("popUpReminders ", 1, 2, "3", "Tin", "Man", Date)
    Application.Run WrapMacro("popUpReminders", 1, 2, "3", "Tin", "Man", Date)
    ActiveSheet.Buttons.Add(0, 0, 72, 72).OnAction = WrapMacro("popUpReminders ", 1, 2, "3", "Tin", "Man", Date)
End Sub

Function WrapMacro(ProcName As String, ParamArray Args() As Variant) As String
    Dim n As Long
    For n = 0 To UBound(Args)
        If TypeName(Args(n)) = "String" Then          'Surround with Double Quotes
            Args(n) = Chr$(34) & Args(n) & Chr$(34)
        ElseIf TypeName(Args(n)) = "Date" Then        'Surround with Hashes
            Args(n) = Chr$(35) & Args(n) & Chr$(35)
        End If
    Next

    WrapMacro = Chr$(39) & ProcName & Space(1) & Join(Args, ",") & Chr$(39)
End Function

Sub popUpReminders(ParamArray Args() As Variant)
    MsgBox Join(Args, vbNewLine)
End Sub
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I hate to say this but you need even *more* quotes :-) However, there's no real need to split out the internal quotes into separate strings, you can just use:

```
Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:05"), "'popUpReminder ""Hello""'"
```

Perhaps a more viewable example would be a function that takes a single integer. That would be:

```
Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:05"), "'checkAnswer 42'"
```

You can see there that the entire statement is quoted.

Answer (score 1):

You need a single quote on either side and a slight reformatting:

```
Sub popUpReminder(msg As String)
    MsgBox (msg)
End Sub

Sub schedulePopUp()
    Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:05"), "'popUpReminder(""Hello"")'"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Another variation for repeating events

```
Sub Test()
For i = 5 To 12
Application.OnTime TimeValue(Format(i, "00") & ":00:00"), "'DoCopy " & i & "'"
Next
End Sub
```