# Assign a macro to userform command button onclick

Tags: vba, button, ms-word, userform

I have a userform with one button and I have some macros written in a module1.

I want that when button is clicked the macros run.
I am trying this in word using VBA

Any suggestions?

Comment: Actually I want to know is how to assign a button in userform to run a particular macro
and also I want to know the steps for word,
I am currently working in word application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there a reason to not put your procedure in the UserForm itself? Is it needed outside the userform?

If not, it should be in the UserForm's code as the click handler for that button.

If it is used outside the UserForm, you could put the following in your click event handler in the form:

```
Application.Run "module1.mymacro"
```

or

```
Call module1.mymacro
```

or even simply

```
mymacro
```

Where the name of the macro you plan on running is named "mymacro."

For more, see:

- [Calling Sub and Function Procedures](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/concepts/getting-started/calling-sub-and-function-procedures), and
- [Application.Run Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.application.run)
- [Difference between Calling a Sub and Application.Run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55266228/difference-between-calling-a-sub-and-application-run)